# jquery ui timepicker onChange Event

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-timepicker

i am Struggling with onchange for JQuery ui timepicker plugin: http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

I am using the following code.

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $('#CutoffTime').timepicker({ stepMinute: 15 });
});
```

// Trying to catch the change event

```
$(function ()
{
    $('#CutoffTime').change(function ()
    {
        // do something heree
    });
});
```

// my HTML

```
<input type="text" id="CutoffTime" />
```

For some reason it seems to go in an infinite loop? is there a better way of achieving what i need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you look farther down the page they have an example that uses onselect

```
$('#CutoffTime').datetimepicker({
    stepMinute: 15,
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst){
        if(window.console)
            console.log(dateText);
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't work for me, no javascript errors, simply function is not being executed, any reason why that would be?